# unique key-value-pair collection

Tags: c#, .net, collections, big-o

Is there any structure that allows **BOTH** of these operations:

- `collection.TryGetValue(TKey, out TValue)`
- `collection.TryGetKey(TValue, out TKey)`

In a better time than O(n)?

**My problem:**

I basically need to be able to retrieve *key's value* or *value's key* really fast, without duplicating the memory (so two dictionaries are out of question).

Very important note: all the keys are unique and all the values are unique. Having this information I *feel* it should be possible to accomplish this task in a better time than just O(1) for `.TryGetValue` and O(n) for `.TryGetKey`.

**EDIT:**

In my case, I have a mapping between `strings` and `ints`. There are ~650,000 key-value pairs of texts and their IDs. So I basically want to get the string with a specific ID but also the ID of a certain string.

Comment: "without duplicating the memory (so two dictionaries are out of question)." using two dictionaries do not duplicate memory unless your `TKey` and `TValue` are both structs.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain they are both structs :)

Comment: I don't know if what you ask is possible. I mean, i don't know much and still have lot to learn but one thing I have always heard about computer science is : "You want it fast ? You need memory. You want it light ? it will be slower." But I favor your question since I'm intresed.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois The official Computer Science term for what you are taking about is the "[Space-Time tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff)" You can trade [memory] space for processing time, the more memory you use the less time it will take, the less memory you use the more time it will take.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois you are right in general but it doesn't means that we cann't do more optimal without memory overhead or speed up solution by using more memory.

Comment: The fact you are storing structs is *very* important regarding the way we could micro-optimize a retrieval process. Please emphase it in your question.

Comment: Is both TKey and TValue a struct or just one of them? (Please update your question with the relevant info)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I updated the question. Sorry for the confusion. Right, one reference type (string) and one value type (int).

Comment: Per the update: At those sizes, have you considered using a lightweight inproc database to hold the lookup table like SQLite? You can make a two column table with a index on both columns.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain although this does not answer the question, it solves the problem for sure. I wish I could upvote you.

Answer (score 4):

To get better than O(n) you will need to use a 2nd dictionary. However as you mentioned you are using structs and are concerned about memory usage with a 2nd dictionary having a duplicate copy of the struct.

One way around this is box the struct value inside a object then share the boxed object in the two dictionaries. If you use inherit from [`DictionaryBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionarybase(v=vs.110).aspx) this is actually quite easy to implement.

```
public sealed class TwoWayDictionary<TKey, TValue> : DictionaryBase
{
    Hashtable reverseLookup = new Hashtable();

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        this.Dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public void Remove(TKey key)
    {
        this.Dictionary.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        object lookup = Dictionary[key];
        if (lookup == null)
        {
            value = default(TValue);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            value = (TValue)lookup;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetKey(TValue value, out TKey key)
    {
        object lookup = reverseLookup[value];
        if (lookup == null)
        {
            key = default(TKey);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            key = (TKey)lookup;
            return true;
        }
    }

    //If OnInsertComplete or OnSetComplete raises a exception DictionaryBase will 
    // roll back the operation it completed.
    protected override void OnInsertComplete(object key, object value)
    {
        reverseLookup.Add(value, key);
    }

    protected override void OnSetComplete(object key, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if(reverseLookup.Contains(newValue))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Duplicate value");
        if(oldValue != null)
            reverseLookup.Remove(oldValue);
        reverseLookup[newValue] = key;
    }

    protected override void OnRemoveComplete(object key, object value)
    {
        reverseLookup.Remove(value);
    }
}
```

The `Dictionary` and `reverseLookup` dictionaries will share the same references so it will have a smaller memory footprint than using two strongly typed dictionaries with large structs.

Without writing a full `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implementation that usees two internal bucket collections for keys and values and two linked lists for the chains off of the buckets I don't think you can get much better results.

Comment: This is a good solution when the TwoWayDictionary is built on runtime, but I am now thinking... Can it actually be serialized and deserialized, maintaining the performance?

Comment: @Randolph It should be, all you need to do is put a `[Serializeable]` attribute and it should be good. Both `DictionaryBase` and `Hashtable` are already marked as serializable. But you would need to test it. If it is not feel free to ask a new question about why it is failing if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some wrapper for `key` which should contains key and link to `value` wrapper and wrapper for `value` which should contains value and link to `key` wrapper. And use two different `HashSet`s.
In this case you avoid memory duplicating. You need only additional memory for links.

Answer (score -2):

you can do such thing ;

```
Dictionary<string, string> types = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                        {"1", "one"},
                        {"2", "two"},
                        {"3", "three"}
            };

            var myValue = types.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "one").Key;
```

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.FirstOrDefault()` is `O(n)`, not `O(1)`.

Comment: I don't know if that comment was meant to be a reply to mine, but see [Wikipedia: Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: well maybe he wants to use a small size list, depends on how many items he wants to store in the dictionary, if it is a large size then it might be a bad idea to use dictionary

Comment: No, it does not depend on how many items. That's exactly what Big O notation does. `O(1)` means you can always look up an item in a time complexity of 1, regardless of how many items are in the collection, while with `O(n)` the lookup of one item scales linearly with the amount of items in the list. Your code shows the latter (`FirstOrDefault()` will, worst case, iterate over all items in the collection), which is explicitly what OP did not request.

Comment: I would be more happy to see your answer

Comment: @Ktt: if there was an answer he would have posted it. I think it should be possible to create such a collection, but there is none in the framework. It would need additional memory but not doubled like with two dictionaries. But if that's not a problem i would use the latter,  it's the easiest way.

Comment: If I knew the answer off the top off my head, I'd have posted it. If I'd have the resources to figure this rather interesting problem out, I'd spend it and post an answer. No need to blame me. :)

Comment: I dont blame you :) you were right about O(n). That's why I wanted to see your answer. @TimSchmelter has a point I guess, maybe implementing your own collection is a better idea

Comment: No problem, happy to help. You can always favorite a question to follow it, see if someone comes up with an answer.